# Can local variable cause memory leak with ARC?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

In this 3 cases I will have memory leak?

- No **__strong** and no set to nil

  ```
  - (void)function {
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: @"Hello World"];
  }
  ```
- No set to nil but use **__strong**

  ```
  - (void)function {
      __strong NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: @"Hello World"];
  }
  ```
- No **__strong** but set nil

  ```
  - (void)function {
      NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: @"Hello World"];
      string = nil;   
  }
  ```

With Automatic Reference Counting (ARC), if I don't set any keyword, I assume the variable is **__strong**?

Comment: Much shorter would be `NSString *string = @"Hello World";`. Within a method no other action is needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't specify an ownership qualifier, it's implicitly `__strong`. Then, at the end of the local scope in which the variable is declared, the compiler inserts a release, regardless of whether you set the variable to nil.

So, your local variable is released in all three cases -- no leak.